# parallel process data from file

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I`m facing a problem with parallel computing data from a big csv file. The issue is that reading from file can not be paralleled but chunks of data from file can be passed for parallel computing. I tried using Multiprocessing.Pool with no result (Pool.imap does not accept yield generator).

I have a generator for reading chunks of data from file. It takes ca. 3 sec. to fetch one chunk of data from file. This chunk of data is processed witch takes ca. 2 sec. I get 50 chunks of data from file. Waiting on next chunk of file I could compute previous chunk "parallel".

Let`s have some code in concept (but does not work in practice).:

```
def file_data_generator(path):
    # file reading chunk by chunk 
    yield datachunk

def compute(datachunk):
    # some heavy computation 2.sec
    return partial_result

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool()
result = p.imap(compute, file_data_generator(path) ) # yield is the issue?
```

What am I doing wrong? Any other tools should I use?
It`s Python3.5

Simple code concept/skeleton appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. The generator bit with `yield` is correct: `imap` *does* take a generator as an argument and runs `next()` on it, so `yield` is correct in this context.

What you were missing was that `imap` is not blocking, that means the `result = p.imap` call is returning even though the processes are not finished yet. You either need to do

```
p.close()
p.join()
```

And then do something with `results` as a whole, or you simply iterate over the result. Here is a working example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

def compute(line):
    # some heavy computation 2.sec
    return len(line)

def file_data_generator(path):
    # file reading chunk by chunk 
    with open('book.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    # start processes, they are still blocked because queue is empty
    # results is a generator and is empty at the start
    results = p.imap(compute, file_data_generator('book.txt'))

    # now we tell pool that we finished filling the queue
    p.close()
    for res in results:
        print(res)
```

Comment: Helo, thanks for quick response, your code works fine !:). This question is part of bigger problem. Maybe you could point me a direction to start with. The issue is below

Comment: @MaciejskiPawel I see that you have removed your answer from here, but where did you open the new question? I cannot see it, and I had the answer already done ;-)